# How can I avoid creating lots overloaded methods?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, overloading

I have a method that I would like to use in different occasions. That means that I want to use the method but each time pass in a different amount of arguments:

Consider this example:

```
public checkInput(Object a, Object b, Object c, Object d) {
    a.someMethod();
    b.someMethod();
    c.someMethod();
    d.someMethod();
}
```

Now I can only use this method `checkInput(...)` when I pass in 4 parameters. However, there are occasions where I only can pass in two parameters for example.

If I would like to call the method like this `checkInput(a, b, null, null);` I will get a `NullPointerException`.

So now I am wondering, will I have to use overloading in this case, meaning that I will have to create

```
public checkInput(Object a) {
    a.someMethod();
}

public checkInput(Object a, Object b) {
    a.someMethod();
    b.someMethod();
}
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define [Variable arity method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1):

```
public checkInput(Object... args) {
    // args is nothing but an array.
    // You can access each argument using indices args[0], args[1], ...
}
```

Now, you can invoke this method using any number of arguments:

```
checkInput(obj);
checkInput(obj1, obj2);
```

Using varargs is similar to using arrays as parameter. But it gives you the flexibility of passing parameters, without creating an array.

But be careful, since the type of var-args is `Object`, it will take any type of argument. You should do appropriate check before using them. 
Also, you can only have a single vararg parameter in your method, and that too should come last in the list of parameter.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. Could you please describe a little more?

Comment: I dont see what this `public checkInput(Object... args)`line is supposed to do. Could you change it into real Java?

Comment: @user2426316. That's real Java. Please click the link in my answer. Also, search for varargs, you will get some useful links related to this concept.

Comment: @user2426316 As a heads-up, you may want to use primitives in the future, and Object won't work in that case, so you'll need to use that specific primitive type or a wider one(as narrowing conversions require casts and possibly precision loss)

Comment: @hexafraction won't `int` be cast to `Integer`? Autoboxing?

Comment: @boxed__l. Here it will be boxed to `Integer` first, and then conversion would take place from `Integer` to `Object`.

Comment: @hexafraction. It will work fine with int primitives too. Real problem will come when trying to use those values in the method.

Comment: @RohitJain Via boxing, you mean? Or requiring changes to the signature?

Answer (score 0):

No. Simply re-use the four param method as

```
public checkInput(Object a) {
    checkInput(a, null, null, null);
}

public checkInput(Object a, Object b) {
    checkInput(a, b, null, null);
}
```

Comment: If i supply the `checkInput(...)`method with `null` I will get a nullpointerexception.

Comment: How is it a better approach? Wont it make more sense to use variable args in this case?

Comment: @Ankur, did I claim it to be? Yes var-args is certainly a better approach. This would however work on pre-Java 5 as well.